# Does Amazon Transcribe always require using S3 storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am just getting started on looking at speech to text conversion.  I want to transcribe mp3 files, but can convert them if needed.  It looks as though the Google and the IBM offerings allow you to send a file and get a transcript back.  However all the examples I see for Amazon require you to somehow put the file to be transcribed into S3 storage before conversion.  Is that right or am I missing something?  Can you just send a file to Amazon and get the transcription back without having to delve into S3?

Answer (score 2):

The `start_transcription_job()` API call requires the input file to be in Amazon S3, in the same region as the Transcribe service being called.

It is also possible to [Use Amazon Transcribe Streaming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/how-streaming.html), which can perform real-time transcription. However, the sample code that has been provided is only in Java.

See: [aws-samples/aws-transcribe-streaming-example-java: Example Java Application using AWS SDK creating streaming transcriptions via AWS Transcribe](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-transcribe-streaming-example-java)

Comment: So I think you are saying yes you have to use S3 and regions and whatever.  Seems too complicated.  The other providers make life easier.  [The streaming won't work for me.  As I said in the question I have files, 50 minute or so recordings of talks/lectures. Getting flooded with thousands of responses is not a way to go for me.  I want a transcript,]

Comment: Yes, you must put the files in Amazon S3 for them to be transcoded. The output is also saved in Amazon S3.

Answer (score 2):

Well, amazon uses s3 to perform the transcribe service and there is no way around it.
Use goolge or ibm one if you are worried about the calls from s3.. but i wont be amazed to see the same response times across all three services.